# How to wrap multiple vnodes in an outer component?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using [Naive UI's autocomplete component](https://www.naiveui.com/en-US/os-theme/components/auto-complete#API) and rendering the auto suggestions using [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#passing-slots) via `h()`. This works fine:

```
const renderSearchResult = option => [
    h(NTag, { size: 'small', type: 'info' }, { default: () => option.type }),
    ' ',
    option.label
];
```

What I can't figure out, though, is how to wrap this whole thing in a containing element and apply a click event to it.

I thought I could do this, but it results in an error.

```
const renderSearchResult = option => h('div', [
    h(NTag, { size: 'small', type: 'info' }, { default: () => option.type }),
    ' ',
    option.label
], {onClick: () => alert('foo')});
```

I must be misusing the third parameter. How can I do this?

Comment: Please, add the relevant tag, as h function differs in Vue 2 and 3. It's unclear what's the purpose of { default: () => option.type }, could be a problem too

Answer (score 1):

[`h` accepts 1-3 arguments](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#creating-vnodes).

Props and children arguments are swapped in one call, should be:

```
h('div', { onClick: () => alert('foo') }, [
    ...
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometimes when a function is so flexible its signature can be a little hard to follow.